# Ricardian on the EOS chain

Tags: ricardian

I have implement Ricardian contract on my contract and can be seen in contract abi file but i have few questions

1. Let say user binds a ricardian contract with my application and perform an transaction so user should be able to see proof that ricardian contract has been sign on the chain with specific version of ricardian contract in case if application admin change ricardian contract then there should be a way for user to find on which version of ricardian contract he binds contract.
2. There should be a way for user to claim on dispute if application don't fulfill the promises written on contract.

If i'm not wrong then this should be soul purpose of ricardian contract on the EOS where user can see the contract on blockchain not only in the form of abi because ricardian contract could be change by application admin and control of authority who can solve the dispute.

Comment: With every transaction save recardian contract this way you can get when needed.